# How to run IdentityServer and WebAPI in same project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

Currently I have an Identity server that runs perfectly, but I want to add an API on top of it to make some database configuration changes through a web front end. The examples in the docs show how to do this with MVC, but not WebAPI.

The Startup.Configuration method looks like this:

```
app.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions{ ... });

...

app.Map("/api", apiApp =>
{
    apiApp.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = "https://localhost:44300", // URL of identity server
    });
});
```

However, when `app.Map` gets called, it throws an error because it can't reach the identity server, presumably because it hasn't started yet. How can I get them to properly work together?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This always happens when I post on StackOverflow, I figured it out seconds after I posted! For anyone else having this issue, in the

`IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions`

set

`DelayLoadMetadata = true`

and then everything will run smoothly!